# LyX: How to add command line option/flag for latex compiling?

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX 1.6.9 with MikTex on Windows XP.

I want to use the "minted" package (for colored listings). This package uses Pygmentize to color the output. However, to do so, it uses \immediate\write18, which basically runs a command.

By default, Latex is not allowed to execute commands and throws instead the following error:

```
runsystem(echo testing)...disabled (restricted).
```

Turns out with Miktex on Windows XP, you must append a flag to the latex command which is to compile your code (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300497/using-minted-source-code-latex-package-with-emacs-auctex):

```
-shell-escape
```

Since I'm using LyX, how do I add a flag / switch / option (whatever you call it) to the Latex command which compiles my LyX code?

I am very reluctant to navigating through Windows' CMD for all my further Latex compiling and I'm pretty sure there is a way to add that in LyX. I haven't found anything on their website nor on Google/Duckduckgo.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under the `Tools` menu, choose `Preferences`.  Then, in preferences dialog, under `File Handling`, in `Converters`, find the one for converting from TeX to PDF that you use (pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex, ...) and edit its command line.

Comment: Thanks it worked marvelously!

P.S.: I'll vote this post up as soon as I get enough reputation...

Answer (score 5):

http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#lyx

it is a german menu but easy to understand

Comment: Thanks for your input and the screenshot. It was helpful.

P.S.: I'll vote this post up as soon as I get enough reputation...