# Calling an external script from LyX

Tags: lyx, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LyX: How to add command line option/flag for latex compiling?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16366/lyx-how-to-add-command-line-option-flag-for-latex-compiling)

Is there a way to call an external script with LyX? Something like the `math-extern` command, that sends the text to an external script and appends the result, but I need to be able to call my own scripts.